# How do you expose a static lib's assembler proc, as a dllexport of the outer DLL?

Tags: c++, assembly, 64-bit, dllexport, win64

As inline assembler is not supported in 64-bit VC++ (2010), I recently converted a 70 page static C++ library of inline functions to a straight 64-bit assembler static lib.  The 64-bit DLL containing the static library then builds without error, and correctly links in the asm functions.  But linking an EXE to the DLL doesn't see the asm functions, getting a LNK2001: unresolved external symbol error for every unique symbol referenced.

The static library assembler code looks something like:

```
public   My_func
My_func  proc
         ...
         endp
```

The DLL containing the static library declares:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) My_func (some_arguments);
```

The EXE that links to the DLL declares:

```
extern "C" My_func (some_arguments);  // __declspec(dllimport) here doesn't help
```

I am using _cdecl throughout and compiling as C++ code everywhere.  I'm running out of things to try, what am I missing here?  I would like to avoid adding a .DEF file to this if possible.

Comment: I would recommend using a def file.

Comment: @Chris - What does the name of an `extern "C"` function look like when actually compiled with a C compiler? `_My_func`?

Comment: Yes, you are correct about _My_func, and that is what ml64 generates for it too.  And it works, now that I have thrown in the towel and used a .DEF file, but additionally able to now make progress on main objectives.  A __decspec solution would be preferable.